# CSS3 Flip (rotate) effect shows it's backface in flip-countdown plugin

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, effects

when trying to implement the [flip countdown lib](http://cnanney.com/journal/demo/css-flip-counter/)

The current number's lower part is being displayed in the current falling tile, which is wrong. As you can see in this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/mBFLA/1/

The drawing is made in this part of the code:

```
ch += '<li class="digit"><div id="digit-a' + i + '" class="digit-wrap"><div class="shadow"></div>' + '<div class="top-new"><span>' + dNew + '</span></div>' + '<div class="digit-hinge"><div class="top-old"><span>' + dOld + '</span></div>' + '<div class="bottom-new"><span>' + dNew + '</span></div></div>' + '<div class="bottom-old"><span>' + dOld + '</span></div></div></li>';
```

May guess is that the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` property is being ignored in the `.top-old` css class.

Note: I'm targeting WebKit for now.

Any tip is appreciated :)

Comment: even the homepage is wrong and you can see `Update: Demo is broken now in Chrome as of v20.0.1132.17. Oh well, don't have the time to mess with it to fix.`

Comment: Can't be too hard to fix - when it goes from 19 to 20 the bottom half of what should be a 2 is an upside down 1, but when it goes from 20 to 21 it automatically fixes itself.